# Communication error when running load test on Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops, load-testing

I'm trying to run load tests on Visual Studio Team Services an I get the following error(see image). My run settings are set to Team Services, I am connected to the account and the account has a valid Visual Studio Enterprise subscription.

All suggestions on what can be causing this is appreciated.

[image: Error message: the request could not be completed as the communication with the service failed. check the inner exception for more details]

Thanks

Comment: Can you still see this issue, there was an issue with VSTS before that caused some customers cannot use Cloud Load Test Service. See this link for details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsoservice/2016/04/27/issues-with-clt-on-visual-studio-team-services-427-investigating/

Comment: Yes this issue is still occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my Visual Studio from 2013 ultimate to 2015 Enterprise and that fixed the issue.